# Send previous day file to server in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm devloping a shell script to scp a.txt to different servers(box1 and box2) and script is running in boxmain server. Below are the requirements,

1. my script will connect to db2 database and generate a.txt file in boxmain
2. a.txt will be scp'ed to box1 once the file is generated
3. The file generated in boxmain(a.txt) will be scp'ed to box2 on the next day, i.e. It will be an SCP of the previous day's boxmain file

Note : box1,box2,boxmain are servers

i tried the below, able to finish first 2 tasks but stuck in 3rd. Please suggest how to achieve the third point. Thanks in advance.

`db2 -tvf query.sql #creates a.txt`
`scp a.txt user@box1:/root/a.txt`

`now=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y")`
`cp a.txt a_$now.txt`

my os version is  `AIX test 1 6`

Comment: try `date -d '1 day ago' +%m/%d/%Y` (maybe not available on AIX)

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight problem with your question definition: using '/' in the name of your source filename will make it interpreted as not just a filename but a path containing directories as well because '/' is the directory separator. It might be a good idea to use `now=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")` instead of `now=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y")`.

But to answer your actual problem which I think boils down to this: how to get date(1) to output a date from yesterday on AIX?

The answer was found from [The UNIX and Linux Forums](http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?t=72068): just set the environment variable describing your timezone to have +24 in it and you'll get yesterdays date from output of `date`.

For example:

user@foo ~]# date
  Mon Nov  4 09:40:34 EET 2013
  user@foor ~]# TZ=EST+24 date
  Sun Nov  3 07:40:36 EST 2013

Applying this to your problem, just set an appropriate value for TZ when you run `now=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y")` ie. use `now=$(TZ=ZONE+24 date +"%m-%d-%Y")` (note the corrections on the path separator and replace ZONE with your own timezone).